# MYSQL - Delete If

Tags: mysql

I have a script that updates a text file daily.  It deletes all the records from the current month as a first step.

```
DELETE FROM salesdata
WHERE year(calendar_date) = year(now()) 
AND month(calendar_date) = month(now());
```

On the first 3 days of the month, the text file includes data from the previous month.  (The way the text file and sales orders are generated, orders can change or be deleted for a few days after it posts.  The easiest way to account for this is just to full refresh daily).

I'd like to do something like this:

```
IF DAY(calendar_date) <= 3
    DELETE FROM salesdata
    WHERE year(calendar_date) = year(now()) 
    AND month(calendar_date) = month(now()) - 1
    OR month(calendar_date) = month(now());
ELSE
    DELETE FROM salesdata
    WHERE year(calendar_date) = year(now()) 
    AND month(calendar_date) = month(now());
```

Can I do this in MYSQL?  I have been looking at the IF and CASE statements but I haven't seen anything that supports this.

Comment: `IF` only works inside stored procedures, not ad-hoc queries.

Comment: Should the `IF` condition be based on `DAY(NOW())`, not `DAY(calendar_date)`?

Comment: Yes, it should be based off Day(Now()). Thanks for the catch

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need `if`? That's why there's `where` clauses...

```
DELETE ...
WHERE (year/month stuff AND (DAY(calendar_date) <= 3))
   OR (..other stuff..)
```

Comment: I think this would just delete only records that are 3 days into the month or less.  I need to condition it to delete both MONTH(now()) and MONTH(now())-1 if DAY() <= 3

Comment: It's just an example. You don't need `if`, because `where` is already essentially a giant `if` already. You just need to rewrite your `where` to accomodate what you're trying to do with that `if`.

Answer (score 0):

`IF` statements can only be used in stored procedures, not in queries. In a query, you need to put the condition into the `WHERE` clause, and you can use the `IF()` function.

```
DELETE FROM salesdata
WHERE YEAR(calendar_date) = YEAR(now())
AND IF(DAY(NOW()) <= 3,
       MONTH(calendar_date) IN (MONTH(NOW(), MONTH(NOW()) - 1),
       MONTH(calendar_date) = MONTH(NOW()))
```

This doesn't deal well with the beginning of the year, though. Instead of comparing year and month, it would be better to compare whole dates and use date arithmetic.

```
DELETE FROM salesdata
WHERE calendar_date >= 
    DATE_FORMAT('%Y-%m-01',
        IF(DAY(NOW()) <= 3, NOW(), DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH)))
```

Comment: What if this is January?

Comment: @juergend That's a better question for the OP.

Comment: This makes sense.  Not sure if there is a way to easily address year end, do you have any suggestion?  I would probably just do a manual check for the first 3 days of the year.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following query:

```
DELETE FROM salesdata
where 
year(calendar_date) = year(now())
AND (
    (DAY(calendar_date)<=3 and month(calendar_date) = month(now())- 1) 
    OR month(calendar_date) = month(now())
)
```